# Macro to copy rows where cells interior color is orange, then paste data to new worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have for the most part it working. I can't seem to get through the CopyRng block to set it for each sheet and gather the entire row where the cells are color filled. `Set CopyRng = sh.Cells().Interior.Color = vbOrange sh.Cells().EntireRow`Can anyone help?

Module1:

```
Function LastRow(sh As Worksheet)
On Error Resume Next
LastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                        After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                        Lookat:=xlPart, _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                        MatchCase:=False).Row
On Error GoTo 0
End Function

Function LastCol(sh As Worksheet)
    On Error Resume Next
    LastCol = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                            After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                            Lookat:=xlPart, _
                            LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                            MatchCase:=False).Column
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Module2:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyRangeFromMultiWorksheets()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim Last As Long
Dim CopyRng As Range
Dim tbl As ListObject

Dim Cell As Range
Dim clrOrange As Long

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Delete the summary sheet if it exists.
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
On Error Resume Next
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SummarySheet").Delete
On Error GoTo 0
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

' Add a new summary worksheet.
Set DestSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
DestSh.Name = "SummarySheet"
Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = "=TODAY()"
Range("A3:G3").Font.Bold = True
Range("A3") = "Vendor"
Range("B3") = "Account#"
Range("C3") = "Job/Dept"
Range("D3") = "Cost Code/Account"

Range("E3") = "PO"
Range("F3") = "Bill Date"
Range("G3") = "Bill Date2"

clrOrange = RGB(255, 192, 0)

' Loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the
' summary worksheet.
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects

    For Each Cell In tbl.DataBodyRange

If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

        ' Find the last row with data on the summary worksheet.
        Last = LastRow(DestSh)

        ' Specify the range to place the data. Select entire row where cells are orange.

If Cell.Interior.Color = clrOrange Then
     If CopyRng Is Nothing Then
         Set CopyRng = Cell
     Else
         Set CopyRng = Union(CopyRng, Cell)
     End If
End If

' This statement copies values and formats from each
' worksheet.

Cell.EntireRow.Copy

        With DestSh.Cells(Last + 1, "A")
            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With

    End If
    Next
    Next
Next

ExitTheSub:

Application.GoTo DestSh.Cells(1)

' AutoFit the column width in the summary sheet.
DestSh.Columns.AutoFit

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have one orange range on each sheet or could there be multiple ones?

Comment: Have a conditional format set to turn a cell orange based on a condition in multiple dynamic tables on each sheet. I need the code to go through each sheet and locate that cell that is orange, copy the entire row in the table, and then combine and paste data on new sheet which I've have called "SummarySheet". If no orange cells are found do nothing.

Comment: Updated code works. I don't get errors, but it is not copy and pasting the rows on the new sheet. Not sure what I am missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am still not able to solve this. Can someone please give some input on a solution, or run it and see if you can get it to work?

Comment: After the revisions I am getting a runtime error object variable not set `CopyRng.Copy`. I change it to `Cell.Copy` and it copies each cell from each table and pastes everything on the summary sheet in only column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through the cells and check each to see if they are orange, then add them to CopyRng one by one:

```
Dim Cell as Range

For Each Cell in sh.Range("A1:A50")      'Or whatever the range is where orange cells can be

    If Cell.Interior.Color = vbOrange Then
        If CopyRng is Nothing then
            Set CopyRng = Cell
        Else
            Set CopyRng = Union(CopyRng, Cell)
        End If
    EndIf
Next

CopyRng.Copy
etc.
```

Comment: Thank you. That gave me some idea. I would like to loop through each table in multiple worksheets. Locate the cell that is orange in that table, then add that entire row to copyrng. I have a new variable `Dim tbl As ListObject` and I know I will need a loop statement such as `For Each tbl In sh.ListObjects` but not sure how to write the rest. Can you help?

Comment: For Each Cell in tbl.DataBodyRange. If you want to add the entire row, then Set CopyRng = Cell.EntireRow, for example.

Comment: Thanks again. i'm getting there. Can you please take a look at the updated code above. I'm getting a error  on line `If Last + CopyRng.Rows.Count > DestSh.Rows.Count Then` indicated object variable or with block variable not set. I didn't change that piece of code as it was fine and worked originally.

Comment: Replace it with If Last + 1 > ....  because CopyRng.Rows.Count will always be 1 in your code.

Comment: I update the code with what you suggested (see module2). I have one table on two worksheets. Each has three rows and 7 columns. The code is not recognizing the colored cells, and pasting each row in the table 7 times. For example, row 1 in table1 pasted 7 times then 2nd row in table1 pasted 7 times and so forth. What is going on...?

Comment: It is because you are looping through each column in each row. You need to only loop through the rows and then copy the entire row once if it is orange.

Comment: Thank you. Added `.Rows` to `For Each Cell In tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows`. But it is pasting all the rows not just the rows that have an orange cell in the row.